# actionbar-pulltorefrsh in Listview has error with API 10 and the same project in API 18 is OK

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The  Error is: Could not find class 'android.animation.AnimatorSet', referenced from method uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.DefaultHeaderTransformer.showHeaderView   How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

`AnimatorSet` was added in API 11 and so if you try to use it in API 10 it will give you error.

Comment: Do you have some other to replace AnimatorSet ,I had to use this project run whit API 10

Comment: Sorry no idea try to check if you could use any support jar